# How to make a marker in Leaflet have two popups? One on mouseover and a different one on click?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I wish to have a title hover over markers on my map, but then have a full popup with different content open up when they are clicked.

I tried to make a legend with a list of all the markers that would function as links for respective popups, but I didn't seem to find how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set different popups for your markers on different events. Here's an example how to set it in point to layer function:

```
    var ptl = function(f, latlng){              
        
        var icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/icon.png',
            iconSize:     [30, 50], // size of the icon
            iconAnchor:   [0, 25]
        });
    
            
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon4}).on('click', function(e) {
                
            this.bindPopup(e.sourceTarget.feature.properties['content']);
        }).on('mouseover', function(e){
            var popup = L.popup({
                offset: [0, -30]
            })
                .setLatLng(e.latlng) 
                .setContent(e.sourceTarget.feature.properties['title'])
                .openOn(map);
                
        }).on('mouseleave', function(e){
            this.closePopup();
        });
            

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the title in your marker options, then bind your popup with content using .bindPopup. If each marker has different popup info, you would need to bind the individual popups to the markers as below:

```
const marker# = L.marker([markerLat,markerLng], {
  title: "markerTitle",
}).bindPopup(
  'HTML POPUPCONTENT GOES HERE', {
    autoPan: false })
```

As an extension - the popup also has options - I included the option for autoPan as an example.

```js
var map = L.map("map", {
  scrollWheelZoom: true,
}).setView([39.5, -98.35], 5);

const osm = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: '',
  noWrap: true,
}).addTo(map);
var icon = new L.icon({
  iconUrl: "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
  shadowUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [16, 16],
  shadowSize: [16, 16],
  iconAnchor: [0, 0],
  shadowAnchor: [-5, -1],
});
const marker = new L.marker([39.5, -98.35], {
  title: "This is a Marker!",
  icon: icon,
}).bindPopup(
  '<table style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;"><th colspan=2 style="text-align:center;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">Table</th><tr><td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">Col 1</td><td style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">Col 2</td></tr></table>', {
    autoPan: false
  }).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```